do-release-upgrade failed to acquire updates from local mirror
Here's the background,
I created an ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS server acting as a local mirror to provide repository to the ubuntu client hosts in an isolated environment.
The acquired files/packages ranging from version bionic to jammy(version 18 to 22) using apt-mirror and the key URLs in the mirror.list are shown below:(note that these URLs are the only ones chosen, no other URLs)
# Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy)
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
# Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

I'm trying to upgrade an Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS client host, which is an OpenVPN Access Server Appliance 2.8.5 to version 20.04 via this local mirror using do-release-upgrade but didn't succeed.
The content of /etc/apt/sources.list file of this ubuntu client has of course been changed to the local mirror's URLs(also the only remaining content), as shown below:
deb http://<local-mirror-IP>/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://<local-mirror-IP>/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://<local-mirror-IP>/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

The "apt update" and "apt upgrade" results were successful on this ubuntu client and all the packages are up-to-date.
After that, since this ubuntu client does not have "do-release-upgrade" therefore the "apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core" was executed and the installation was successfull.
Now here's the issue.
After executing do-release-upgrade, it failed to acquire updates from local mirror repository and the error messages are shown below:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

I tried changing the beginning of the "URI" and "URI_LTS" in the meta-release file from https to http but apparently this isn't the solution. Error messages are similar.
And please note that changing the release upgrade from "LTS" to "normal" didn't help either. do-release-upgrade -c cannot acquire new release too.
Also tried this method:

download the "https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts" file from internet
putting this file to the local mirror server's directory of repository so that there are "meta-release" and "meta-release-lts" existing.
edit "meta-release" and "meta-release-lts" files' content with my local mirror's URLs
edit the content of meta-release file on this ubuntu client, change the URI and URI_LTS to URI = http://<local-mirror-IP>/ubuntu/meta-release and URI_LTS = http://<local-mirror-IP>/ubuntu/meta-release-lts respectively.
execute do-release-upgrade again.

And this method failed too, the error messages are shown below:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
ERROR:root:parse failed for '/root/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release-lts'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 379, in download
    self.parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 249, in parse
    "Required key '%s' missing" % required_key)
UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease.MetaReleaseParseError: Required key 'Dist' missing
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

In order to fix this python3-related issue, also tried reinstall the phython3 and related packages, and the apt --fix-broken install
Still in vain.
Note that the openssl version installed on this ubuntu client is openssl/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23 amd64 and the version of python3 is 3.6.9, which are logically the latest version for ubuntu 18.
Can anyone give me some hints please?
I've successfully upgraded other ubuntu 18 system with do-release-upgrade and local mirror repository to newer distribution, and they do not need any change to the configuration of do-release-upgrade but this one just can't. Don't get it.
